# change httprequest ip same with client side

Tags: c#, asp.net, http

i want to change ip when make a httprequest same with ip of mine
for example:
ip when make httprequest: 63.67.128.199
my ip: 222.213.245.90

i want to change 63.67.128.199 to 222.213.245.90

Can i do that?

Comment: Your question in unclear, are you trying to intercept tcp requests and redirect them to localhost?

Comment: i mean, httprequest is server-side, now i want to change httprequest is client-side.

Comment: What are you trying to do? Use a specific interface? Spoof an ip? Add some context and code to clarify.

Comment: i trying to get download link from the website by using httprequest, the ip get link and the ip download link is different, so i want to change ip get same with the ip download

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use server side functions on client side. If you want to have the client do a request you will have do it via javascript, if possible.

Comment: how can i do httprequest with cookiecontainer in javascript?

Comment: I am still not clear on what you're trying to achieve here. It seems to me that you are trying to do something on server side which should be done by the client altogether. Sorry that i can't be more helpful without seeing some code and knowing your exact requirements.